# Lopping over arrays in typescript

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, typescript

I can't seem to grasp over looping arrays/objects. I get stuck pretty often in them. Like here for example I cant iterate the data from the api, I am getting the `trending is not a function` error. Can somebody help me fix this, and give me some good direction to get better at looping

**Interface**

```
export interface Item {
    id: string;
    name: string;
    symbol: string;
    market_cap_rank: number;
    thumb: string;
    large: string;
    score: number;
}

export interface Coin {
    item: Item;
}

export interface ResponseObject{
    coins: Coin[];
   
}
```

**Code**

```
import React, { useEffect, useState} from 'react'
import axios from  'axios'
import { ResponseObject } from '../interfaces';
const TRENDING = 'https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/search/trending'
const Home:React.FC= () => {
  
    const [trending, setTrending ] = useState<ResponseObject[]>([])
    useEffect(()=>{
        axios
        .get<ResponseObject[]>(TRENDING)
        .then((response) => 
        {setTrending(response.data); 
        console.log(response) })
        .catch(err =>
        { console.log(err); })
    },[])

    return (
        <div>  
           {trending.map(trend =>
           (<div key={trend.item.id}>{trend.item.name}</div>))}
        </div>
    )
}

export default Home
```

**Api**

```
{
   "coins":[
      {
         "item":{
            "id":"superfarm",
            "name":"SuperFarm",
            "symbol":"SUPER",
            "market_cap_rank":235,
            "thumb":"https://assets.coingecko.com/coins/images/14040/thumb/6YPdWn6.png?1613975899",
            "large":"https://assets.coingecko.com/coins/images/14040/large/6YPdWn6.png?1613975899",
            "score":0
         }
      },
      {...}
   ],
   "exchanges":[]
}
```

Comment: shouldn't you be passing `response.data.coins` to setState?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you have probably set an object as trending instead of an array. `response.data` should return an object which will be similar to your API.

```
// response.data should return this object.
{
   "coins":[
      {
         "item":{
            "id":"superfarm",
            "name":"SuperFarm",
            "symbol":"SUPER",
            "market_cap_rank":235,
            "thumb":"https://assets.coingecko.com/coins/images/14040/thumb/6YPdWn6.png?1613975899",
            "large":"https://assets.coingecko.com/coins/images/14040/large/6YPdWn6.png?1613975899",
            "score":0
         }
      },
      {...}
   ],
   "exchanges":[]
}
```

You should set `response.data.coins` as trending which will return an array.

```
[
      {
         "item":{
            "id":"superfarm",
            "name":"SuperFarm",
            "symbol":"SUPER",
            "market_cap_rank":235,
            "thumb":"https://assets.coingecko.com/coins/images/14040/thumb/6YPdWn6.png?1613975899",
            "large":"https://assets.coingecko.com/coins/images/14040/large/6YPdWn6.png?1613975899",
            "score":0
         }
      },
      {...}
]
```

Comment: I am getting property "coins" does not exist on type Response Object

Comment: Can you please `console.log(response)` and share here?

Comment: here you go, sorry I was not here https://imgur.com/POxMzvY

Comment: @Tequila I made a sandbox for you: https://codesandbox.io/s/api-coingecko-1qnu9

Comment: @Ajeet Shah why I needed to in a useState hook to pass Coin instead ResponseObject interface

Comment: `response.data` is of type `ResponseObject` (as you specified in `axios.get`). `response.data.coins` is `Coins[]` (array of coins). And, I wrote `setTrending(response.data.coins);` at API success. That means I am setting `response.data.coins` (of type `Coin[]`) in state i.e. `trending`. So, I need to tell `useState` that, I will be setting `Coin[]` type of data with you. That's why, I wrote `useState<Coin[]>([]);`.

Comment: @Tequila because `ResponseObject` is not an array.

Comment: is there any guide to get better at this stuff, or it is just pure practice. I will probably stunt into some nested objects in the future

Comment: When I was trying TS for the first time, I used to often go to the official site to read about it: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/basic-types.html @Tequila

Answer (score 1):

The problem has nothing to do with looping.

You are calling `setTrending` with something that is not an array. that's why you are getting `trending.map is not a function`.

Your API is not directly returning an array, but an objet with two keys, each one holding an array.

In your case, you have to call `setTrending(response.data.coins)`.

EDIT: you should also fix your `ResponseObject` usage:

```js
const [trending, setTrending ] = useState<Coin[]>([]);

useEffect(()=> {
    axios
      .get<ResponseObject>(TRENDING)
      .then((response) =>  {
        setTrending(response.data.coins); 
    })
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
},[]);
```

Comment: I am getting property "coins" does not exist on type Response Object